# syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file

Tags: php

I'm writing in php and when I tried to run it, it gave me an error:
`syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file`
This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
    <?php
$outputNumber=0;
$inputNumber = (float)$_POST['inputNumber'];
$inputFormat = $_POST['inputFormat'];
$outputFormat = $_POST['outputFormat'];

    switch($inputFormat){
    case "meter":

        switch ($outputFormat){
        case "pico": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*1000000000000;break;  
        case "nano": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*1000000000;break;  
        case "micro": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*1000000;break;  
        case "mm": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*1000;break;  
        case "cm": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*100;break;
        case "deci": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*10;break;         
        case "meter": $outputNumber = $inputNumber;break;
        case "deca": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*0.1;break;
        case "hm": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*0.01;break;
        case "km": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*0.001;break;
        }
    break;
    }
echo $outputNumber;

   ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

What is the problem here ? I tried removing all the switches and cases and it still gave me the same error.

Comment: Is there any `php` files included in this file ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: This is why you should indent properly. Things will get more obvious.

Comment: What's shown here doesn't actually cause that error...

Answer (score 3):

Very simple you work with nested switch statements. That only works if you put the nested switch in brackets.

```
switch($inputFormat){
    case "meter": {
                ^^^^
    switch ($outputFormat){
    case "pico": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*1000000000000;break;  
    case "nano": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*1000000000;break;  
    case "micro": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*1000000;break;  
    case "mm": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*1000;break;  
    case "cm": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*100;break;
    case "deci": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*10;break;         
    case "meter": $outputNumber = $inputNumber;break;
    case "deca": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*0.1;break;
    case "hm": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*0.01;break;
    case "km": $outputNumber = $inputNumber*0.001;break;
    }
    break;
   }
}
```

Otherwise you have a syntax error.

Comment: Still gives me the same error.

Comment: Actually if you copy **exactly** what's shown and paste it into an empty PHP file it works fine (I replaced `$_POST` with `$_REQUEST` so I could just drop the vars in the URL - but that was it). Using PHP 5.6.8 on Apache 2.4. I suspect there's something else going on.